# Get git commit list between tags from remote

Tags: git, github

If there any way I can retrieve all commits between tags from remote master? So far what I did is checkout to master branch and update the repo then fire the following command.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git log tag1..tag2 --pretty=format:'* %h %an: %s (%cr)' -- .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the branch for `git log`

```
git fetch
git log origin/master tag1..tag2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I[s] there any way I can retrieve all commits between tags from remote master?

It is not clear to me what you mean by *retrieve*, nor, for that matter, what you mean by *between*.  But in general, in most cases, you can just run `git fetch` and use the tag names in *your* repository.  Your repository will contain copies of the tag names in their repository.  If necessary, you can run `git fetch --tags`; see below.

#### Long

Remember that in general, a Git repository contains *all* commits: one clone is as good as another.<sup>1</sup>  If some clone has some new commits that you don't yet have, you simply run `git fetch` to have your Git call up their Git and have their Git give to you the commits that you did not have; and now you have all of their commits.  (They probably have most of yours, but if you have some they did not have, you still have those and they still don't.)

What branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and any other names *do* in a repository is let you pick out any one particular commit.  That is, *every* commit has a unique name, which is its big ugly hash ID, such as `c7a62075917b3340f908093f63f1161c44ed1475`.  These names are terrible for humans so we mostly don't use them.  Instead, we have Git remember some specific commit(s) for us, under some sort of human-readable name like `master`—a branch name—or `v2.1`, a tag name.  Multiple human-readable names can refer to the same Git hash name.

The key differences between a *branch* name like `master` and a *tag* name like `v2.1` are:

1. Branch names *should* move over time, so that we can have more commits.  In fact, they're so mobile that they move *automatically:* when you `git checkout` some branch name, then make a new commit, the branch name *automatically* identfiies the new commit you just made.  The new commit itself links back, in Git's usual backwards fashion, to the previous branch-tip commit.

   Tag names, by contrast, should never move.  If tag `xyz` names commit `c7a62075917b3340f908093f63f1161c44ed1475` today, it should name that same commit tomorrow.  It should have named that same commit yesterday, too, if the tag name existed yesterday.  Some software actually depends on this.<sup>2</sup>
2. Branch names are *private*, not shared.  When you clone a repository, your clone *renames* all their *branch* names to become your *remote-tracking names*.  That is, their `master` becomes your `origin/master`.<sup>3</sup>  Of course you're *allowed* to create your own branch names, and then keep them in sync, but *you* have to then keep them in sync: Git does not do that automatically.<sup>4</sup>

   *Tag* names, by contrast, are meant to be shared across all clones.  When you clone a repository that has tags `v1.0` through `v1.7`, for instance, you get your own tag names `v1.0` through `v1.7`, but they're literally exactly the same as the original repository's `v1.0` through `v1.7`.  When you run `git fetch` and pick up new commits, if one of those is tagged `v1.8`, you get a new `v1.8`.<sup>5</sup>

Because of these rules, it's usually unnecessary to do anything special.  If you `git clone <url>` you get their commits and their tags, and every subsequent `git fetch origin` gets you any new commits they created, along with any new tags they made for the new commits.  If they go back and add new tag names for *old* commits, though, you may occasionally need to run `git fetch --tags`, as noted in footnote 5.

The issue with talking about commits *between* some particular chosen commits is that commits form a Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG, not just a simple linear chain.  If we have a linear chain like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ...
```

then the notion of *between* is clearer: the commits between F and H, including both edges, are `F`, `G`, and `H`, though in the other order since Git works backwards.  If we have two tag names, pointing at commits `F` and `H` respectively:

```
...--F--G--H--...
     ^     ^
     |     |
  tag:v1 tag:v2
```

then the Git notation `v1..v2` (note two dots here) selects commits `H` and `G`.  The reason `F` is excluded is that `v1..v2` really means `v2 ^v1`, i.e., select all commits starting at `H` and working backwards: `H`, `G`, `F`, and everything before `F` too; but then select commits starting at `F` and working backwards, and *throw those out of the list*.  So from `H`, `G`, `F`, and before, we remove the `F`-and-before part, leaving just `H` and `G`.

To avoid excluding commit `F`, we just need to start the excluding with whatever commit(s) come *before* `F`.  That way we get `H` and `G` and `F`, and toss out whatever is earlier (obviously commit `E` ).

But we can make commit chains that branch (and later maybe merge):

```
         tag:v1.4
             |
             v
          I--J--...
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L--...
             ^
             |
         tag:v1.3
```

Which commits are *between* `v1.4` and `v1.3`?  Git has an answer; it's up to you to decide whether that answer makes sense for your use-case.  (Git's answer is that `v1.3..v1.4` selects commits `J` and `I`, but not `L` nor `K` nor `H`, nor anything before `H`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Shallow clones are a big exception to this rule, but we can assume your clone is not shallow since you did not mention that.

<sup>2</sup>For instance, the Go module system assumes Git tag names never move from one Git commit to another.  This allows it to cache the tag-to-hash-ID mapping.

<sup>3</sup>Note that the kind of clone that the "fork" button achieves on most hosting providers is an exception here: it copies their fork's branch names to your fork's branch names.  But after that, the two are independent.

<sup>4</sup>This ignores what Git calls a *mirror clone*, but again, that's OK: we are presumably not talking about mirror clones here.

<sup>5</sup>This is all under your control: `git fetch --tags` gets all tags, `git fetch --no-tags` gets no tags, and the default is a sort of weird mixture where you get the tags that go with the commits you're getting, but not any other tags.  A later `git fetch --tags` will create new tags, if they created new tags for old commits.  You can also run `git fetch` with various other options to force tag creation and/or update and/or pruning.

Comment: What I want is . Get all commit between tags from remote master so even I know my local master branch is out of date and still can get correct commits without using git fetch to update my local branch

Comment: You still haven't defined *between*. As long as the two tags point to two commits, and you have copies of those tags in *your* repository, you also have the commits; the remainder of *your* job is to define "between". Note, too, that you **must** use `git fetch`. It is not optional. But `git fetch` does not update *your* **branch** names, it updates your **remote-tracking** names (and may also update tags as described above).

Comment: What I mean between means from github I can see some commit marks as tags and some marks as tags and if I run git log tag1...Have I can list out all commit from tag1 and gave. But let's say of lots of people push commit from their branch and merge into master. The new tag is created let's call it gave and tag4 from my local if if I do not run git pull or git fetch. I cannot see tag3 and tag4 then I will get fatal error from git if I run the same git of command. So my questions is if any way I do not need to call git pull/git fetch I can still find all co.mit from tag3 and tag4

Comment: Not with Git, no. You must *have* the commits to *see* the commits. If you wish to use the GitHub interface to do REST calls to GitHub, rather than using Git, you could try that.